# SUDO Keeps promting for password, when using SSSD with AD

Tags: active-directory, redhat, sudo, pam, sssd

Hi I am trying to setup SSSD to authenticate to AD on RHEL.

I able able to login with my AD user and password and see my groups when I run `id`. But when I try to use sudo, it just keeps prompting for my password (`Sorry, please try again`). Any ideas why? I know it is not the sudoers file because when I run  `sudo -U myUser -l` I `see (root) ALL` But I can `su` to root no problem, and I don't get prompted for a password.

My assumption is it has something to do with PAM.

pam.d/system-auth-ac

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_localuser.so
auth        [success=done ignore=ignore default=die] pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so
```

pam.d/password-auth-ac

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        [default=1 success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth        [success=done ignore=ignore default=die] pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
domains = myDomain
services = nss, pam, pac

[domain/myDomain]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
ad_server = adSer2.ca,adSer1.ca
ad_access_filter = memberOf=CN=IT - Shared Services,OU=Infrastructure,OU=CompanyGrps,DC=company,DC=ca
default_shell = /bin/bash
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
ignore_group_members = true
debug_level = 1

[nss]

[pam]
debug_level = 1
pam_verbosity = 3

[pac]
```

nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss ldap
#initgroups: files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss ldap

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss ldap
aliases:    files nisplus
```

sudoers

```
root  ALL=(ALL)   ALL

%it\ -\ shared\ services ALL = (root) ALL
```

**Update**

I got it to work by removing kerberos from the PAM configuration, but I am not sure by doing this if I have introduced a security risk.

Comment: any chance you could show /etc/sudoers as well?

Comment: Added the couple line present

Comment: is this a RHEL7 box authenticating with a Windows 2008R2 domain?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've had to qualify the domain of the group in `/etc/sudoers`

So my sudoers declaration would look more like this:

`%adgroup@domain.local ALL = (root) ALL`

Since you've got spaces in the group name, something like:

`%it\ -\ shared\ services@domain.local ALL = (root) ALL`

Comment: Tried that, couldn't get it to work. As mentioned, when I run sudo -U myUser -l I can see that I have sudo privileges. So, I do not believe its an issue with sudo. It is an issue with how sudo authenticates.